# Can augmented reality "map points" be sent to a friend's phone?

Tags: facebook, api, geolocation, augmented-reality

Does anyone know anything about the underlying details of the augmented reality apps that let you place an AR map marker where your car is? How is that marker saved? Is it saved to the cloud and then back to the phone?

I'm trying to think about how I could achieve a similar effect. I want users to be able to create these AR markers but have them be intended for the user's contacts. So I put a marker on my car and send that "marker" to my friend so he knows where I'm parked.

I have a lot more questions but am interested to hear if anyone has any thoughts/experience on this topic. It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most (mobile) AR points are just coordinates in the WGS-84 coordinate system ("GPS coordinates"), same as map-points on any online mapping service.  Most mobile AR apps have no way of determining local terrain or accurate 3D positioning, so often everything is approximated to a plane locally, so the coordinates are only two dimensional (latitude, longitude) points rather than (lat, lon, altitude).

There are [geocoding and reverse-geocoding APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/), so you could put a pin in a map where you car is, and then send your friend the street-address, which is more human readable, in addition to the actual GPS coordinate.